# history.push not working when using BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

```
//startup file
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router';
 let root=(<BrowserRouter>
            //Some components
         </BrowserRouter>);                                                                  
 ReactDOM.render(Root, document.getElementById("app"));    

// function to navigate or route
import createBrowserHistory from 'history lib createBrowserHistor';
const history = createBrowserHistory();

let browseTo=function(path){
     history.push({pathname: path})
})
```

After calling above Function only URL path changing actual route is not perform.

Like URL `localhost:8080` changes to `localhost:8080/login` not routing to login component.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4059

browserHistory is not exposed by react-router in v4, only in v2.